# How can I trim the Decimals from these search results?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, search-results

I have a built **custom search template** for a SharePoint Online site collection to return results in a tabular form. The template works and returns the desired data but some of it is not in the format I want. The code is below:

```
<body>
    <div id="Item_Default">
<!--#_ 
        if(!$isNull(ctx.CurrentItem) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl)){
            var id = ctx.ClientControl.get_nextUniqueId();
            var itemId = id + Srch.U.Ids.item;
            var hoverId = id + Srch.U.Ids.hover;
            var hoverUrl = "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/Item_Default_HoverPanel.js";
            $setResultItem(itemId, ctx.CurrentItem);
            if(ctx.CurrentItem.IsContainer){
                ctx.CurrentItem.csr_Icon = Srch.U.getFolderIconUrl();
            }
            ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getShowHoverPanelCallback(itemId, hoverId, hoverUrl);
            ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback = Srch.U.getHideHoverPanelCallback();
_#-->
            <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(itemId) =#_" name="Item" data-displaytemplate="DefaultItem" onmouseover="_#= ctx.currentItem_ShowHoverPanelCallback =#_" onmouseout="_#= ctx.currentItem_HideHoverPanelCallback =#_">
                <table cellpadding="4" width="700px">
                <tr>
                <td width="20%" style="text-align:center">_#=ctx.CurrentItem.UPRNOWSNMBR=#_</td>
                <td width="40%" style="text-align:center">_#=ctx.CurrentItem.FullAddress=#_</td>
                <td width="20%" style="text-align:center">_#=ctx.CurrentItem.PlanningCategory_0=#_</td>
                <td width="20%" style="text-align:center">_#=ctx.CurrentItem.PropertyUse=#_</td>
                </tr>
                </table> 
                <div id="_#= $htmlEncode(hoverId) =#_" class="ms-srch-hover-outerContainer"></div>

            </div>
<!--#_ 
        } 
_#-->
    </div>
</body>
```

The column **UPRNOWSNMBR** only contains whole numbers but it returns it's data with a decimal point like this: **12345.00000**

I've created templates that alter data formats on the fly before (changing date format etc) but can't recall how I did it. How can I trim out the decimal point and everything after it leaving the number intact?

Comment: Alternatively you could also create new property with  Type = Integer if the existing UPRNOWSNMBR  type is **Decimal**.Map the crawled property of existing UPRNOWSNMBR  to the new one. This can be done in Search Schema of the Search service application.

Comment: The type is TEXT. In sharepoint online you can only create TEXT and YES/NO type managed properties

Comment: In that case, you can map the crawled property of UPRNOWSNMBR to any of the pre existing Integer type managed property. You can search with Int in schema

Answer (score 2):

If you know that you have a number 100% of the time with decimal places other than 0, you could transform it using javascript.

```
parseInt(_#=ctx.CurrentItem.UPRNOWSNMBR=#_)
```